# MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 PHP memory size error

Tags: php

In a code base I have inherited, there is this line which encodes an error message before displaying on an error page.

```
        $sErrorMessageCrypted = wordwrap(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($sKey), $sMessage, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($sKey)))), 60, PHP_EOL, true);
```

The error is PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 81 bytes).

The error message it receives as input is 1674 characters long, with a 23 character salt.

So, am wondering about the processes here and why this uses so much memory. I presume this is so the error can be displayed without anyone being able to read it. (Although I see nowhere where the previous developer has a decrypt function available).

Any suggestions on changing this?

Thanks

Comment: your script is running close to the ram limit, and then the extra little bit of ram needed to hold the new string is jumping over the line. There's nothing "wrong" with this code as-is, you're just running with a too small ram limit for what you're doing. Without knowing anything else about the rest of the script, there's very little we can do to help, other than "don't use so much memory", or "raise the limit".

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that pulling in the OpenSSL crypto libs pushed you over the 128MB limit.  Increasing the memory limit is the simplest fix.  If you can't do that you could rebuild the libraries and eliminate unneeded ciphers to reduce the size.

Comment: I can increase the server up from 128MB limit, but if this is happening on every exception then it's going to put a strain on the server if many people hit a similar issue at once. I may have to see what the memory usage is for each step .. perhaps using memory_get_usage(). Rather than hide an issue, I'd prefer to fix it or at least understand it. It's definitely just this line that uses so much memory. I presume it's the mcrypt_encrypt that uses up all the memory, but I should probably test it than guess. I was just wondering if there was an obvious reason for so much memory being used.

Comment: Note that this is a virtual memory limit, so mapping lots of code that is never run puts no strain on the server.  You need to look at other stats to see how much physical memory is actually used.